# Why does the blockinfile module only add one line to the file?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use blockinfile module of ansible to write block text into file.

test purpose to `/tmp/hosts`, here is the content of `blockinfile-test.yaml`

```
---
- hosts: web
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Add mappings to /tmp/hosts
    blockinfile:
      path: /tmp/hosts
      create: yes
      block: |
        {{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}
    loop:
      - { name: host1, ip: 10.180.104.100 }
      - { name: host2, ip: 10.180.104.101 }
```

This is inventory file

```
[myself]
ansible-main.local

[web]
10.180.104.101
```

Then ran command to apply

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts  blockinfile-test.yaml

TASK [Add mappings to /tmp/hosts] *****************************
changed: [10.180.104.101] => (item={'name': 'host1', 'ip': '10.180.104.100'})
changed: [10.180.104.101] => (item={'name': 'host2', 'ip': '10.180.104.101'})

PLAY RECAP ********************
10.180.104.101 : ok=1  changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0  ignored=0
```

Then, I checked that effort but got only one line was appended in file `/tmp/hosts`

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
10.180.104.101 host2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Why is only one line written to the file?

Is there missing something to blockinfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create unique [*marker*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker) of the blocks. Otherwise, the blocks will overwrite each other, e.g.

```yaml
  - name: Add mappings to /tmp/hosts
    blockinfile:
      marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ item.name }}"
      path: /tmp/hosts
      create: true
      block: |
        {{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}
    loop: "{{ data }}"
    vars:
      data:
        - {name: host1, ip: 10.180.104.100}
        - {name: host2, ip: 10.180.104.101}
```

will create the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/hosts 
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK host1
10.180.104.100 host1
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK host1
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK host2
10.180.104.101 host2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK host2
```

---

A next option would be iterating the list in the block, e.g.

```yaml
  - name: Add mappings to /tmp/hosts
    blockinfile:
      marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK data"
      path: /tmp/hosts
      create: true
      block: |
        {% for item in data %}
        {{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    vars:
      data:
        - {name: host1, ip: 10.180.104.100}
        - {name: host2, ip: 10.180.104.101}
```

will create the file with a single block. This would make the file easier to read

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/hosts 
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK data
10.180.104.100 host1
10.180.104.101 host2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK data
```

The disadvantage is that you'll have to update the whole block if anything changes. In the first case, you'll be able to update single hosts.

---

You can use [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) to update the blocks, e.g.

```yaml
  - name: Update mappings in /tmp/hosts
    lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/hosts
      create: true
      regexp: '^\s*(.*?)\s+{{ item.name }}\s*$'
      line: "{{ item.ip }} {{ item.name }}"
    loop: "{{ data }}"
    vars:
      data:
        - {name: host1, ip: 10.180.104.100}
        - {name: host2, ip: 10.180.104.101}
```

is idempotent

```yaml
TASK [Update mappings in /tmp/hosts] ******************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'host1', 'ip': '10.180.104.100'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'host2', 'ip': '10.180.104.101'})
```

---

**Notes**

- See [*hosts.yml*](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/hosts.yml) on how to validate the data and create the file from a template
- See example of a [*template*](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/templates/hosts-aliases-list.j2)
- And example of [*data*](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/vars/main.yml.sample#L108) for this template.